# How to get data from database

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I can't get data from a table to a listbox. I try to make a query to search book by name and place it to listbox but its always return **Book not available**, I don't know exactly what's wrong with my code. Here's the code:

```
try
{
    conn.Open();
    _listbox.Items.Clear();
    SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM buku WHERE nama LIKE '%@bookname%'", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@bookname", _search);
    SqlCeDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteResultSet(ResultSetOptions.Scrollable);
    if (r.HasRows)
    {
        while (r.Read())
        {
            _listbox.Items.Add(r[0].ToString());
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        _listbox.Items.Add("Book Not Available");
    }
}
```

I tried to make a query like this:

```
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM buku WHERE nama LIKE '%'+@bookname+'%'", conn);
```

Error message:

> @bookname: Q - Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: How the database column looks like? Could you please post us some data from the database to see the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM buku WHERE nama LIKE @bookname", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@bookname","%"+ _search+"%");
```

Since you use parameters you don't have to quote the parameter.

Also since you only use the 1st field of the result, I would sugest to write you select like:

```
"SELECT fieldImInterestedIn FROM buku WHERE nama LIKE @bookname"
```

Answer (score 0):

do as below,

```
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM buku WHERE nama LIKE @bookname", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bookname", "%"+ _search+ "%");
```

Comment: i believe you don't need quotes